# Is the dual space of a vector space V isomorphic to the space of all linear projections of V onto a 1 dimensional subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

It seems like all projections of a vector $v \in V$ to a 1-dimensional subspace represents a method of mapping $v$ to the base field $\mathbb{F}$. Is it necessarily isomorphic? And would any structures need to be defined on $V$ (e.g. metric, inner product) in order to identify this isomorphism?

Comment: What is this "space of linear projections"? What exactly are you mapping the linear functionals to, rank 1 linear maps on $V$?

Comment: Yes, I meant the rank 1 linear maps on $V$.

Comment: Such maps are parametrized by a pair, a linear functional $l$ and a (unit) vector $u$, so $Av=\langle l,v\rangle u$, not just a linear functional itself.